# Save or log image generated in Karma/Mocha test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-mocha

As part of my Karma/Mocha unit test suite, I generate canvas image and compare it with known "good" image with https://github.com/mapbox/pixelmatch.

However, if such test fails, I need to include the "bad" image into my test report one way or the other, so that it can be later retrieved for inspection.

What would be the right way to do that? Is it possible out of box with some plugins? Obviously, filesystem object is not available in browser under Karma, I cannot just save these images into my reports folder.

One option I have in mind is record base64-encoded image as part of the test fail error, and output it with some custom reporter. Am I missing simpler approach?

Comment: Another possible option: invoke "image save" on server-side with https://github.com/featurist/karma-server-side . Still hope to hear about less "kludgy" approach.

Comment: I'm not familiar with karma but if you use phantoms you can do a screenshot http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html. What headless browser are you using?

Comment: @SteveB ideally I want to keep test browser-agnostic (runnable in browser. or in Puppeteer, or on Node with node Canvas implementation). As I already have my image in unit test as canvas or as base64 string, this is more of a question: how do I pass this "image blob" from test in browser to test runner in Karma or in other similar frameworks. Answering your specific question: I am open to various options for this new project, but currently using Puppeteer for unit tests and Selenium with real browsers for end-to-end test.